# React Query Select Inference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript, react-query

I am trying to write a custom useQuery hook to fetch a list of exercises. The hook should also accept an optional select function. In the case where the optional select function is provided, the type of the data that the `useQuery` hook returns should be of type `number`. When the select function is not provided, the type of should be `PaginatedExerciseInfo<Exercises>`.

I am having trouble implementing this in a way that doesn't upset typescript. Currently, when I call the hook without passing a select function to it (shown below), the data it returns is always of type `number`.

```
const { data: exercises, isError, isLoading, refetch } = useGetExercises<Exercise>(muscleGroup);
```

As I haven't passed a select to it, I was hoping in this case exercises would be of type `PaginatedExerciseInfo<Exercises> | undefined`

So far, I have tried to write the hook like this

```
export const getExercises = async (muscleGroup: MuscleGroup, page: number, perPage: number) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/exercises/${muscleGroup}?page=${page}&per_page=${perPage}&sort=-date`);
  return data;
};

export const useGetExercises = <Exercises extends string>(muscleGroup: MuscleGroup, select?: (data: PaginatedExerciseInfo<Exercises>) => number) => {
  const { page, perPage } = useContext(PaginationContext);
  return useQuery<
    PaginatedExerciseInfo<Exercises>, 
    unknown, 
    typeof select extends undefined ? PaginatedExerciseInfo<Exercises> : number
  >({
    queryKey: [muscleGroup, 'exercises', page, perPage],
    queryFn: () => getExercises(muscleGroup, page, perPage),
    select: select
  });
};
```

Hovering over the `useQuery` function, I can see that the conditional type I've written for the third generic passed into useQuery is always interpreted as `undefined`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve using typescript?

Comment: `select?` means (roughly speaking) `something|undefined` which always extends undefined. This is all that can be known at compile time

Answer (score 13):

To make `select` work in TypeScript, you mainly need:

- 1 generic `TData` to infer the return type
- have that generic default to whatever the QueryFunction returns
- leverage type inference

I've simplified your types a bit, so assuming that `getExercises` returns `Promise<Exercises>`, we can do:

```
export const useGetExercises = <TData = Exercises>(muscleGroup: MuscleGroup, select?: (data: Exercises) => TData) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [muscleGroup, 'exercises'],
    queryFn: () => getExercises(muscleGroup),
    select: select
  });
};
```

now `TData` will be `Exercises` if we pass no select, and it will be whatever select returns if we pass it.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC%20cAZlBCHAOQACMAhgHaoMDGA1gPRTr2swBaAI458VALAAoUJFhx6AD2ARUAGkRwAgkpUBRKOShFS5SlUXLUEyVJh4w6OAFk0rADboA4uWRg4AXjgWKGBGAHNbe0ddBVxWYAxUAK0DejwAHmDQsIA%20KSl0BVl4VghmeDD0GBi4hPQkwPpUPEZWOAAKEFcPbwhfAC5nbq8fMABKQYAFUzr0mqh4xJyA5YQpODgeGGQoRjhpijqAOh5UCDcAN3R2gG0AIhIICDv1O4Ajeig7gF0xqUIANz5SSFYpwUrlFAYTxVeaLerJdIAFQAIvQGMk4XVUDlOsNegMhqh3CM%20mB1BgPPwAPyDdoAE3R9EGWMSYxWcFRTPZ-lW602VR2ezQWFEeHaa0kGw2IlweAA0ug8IMbl1iT1RuoqIVaokqN9VPyZWKAGKMOk85aVaqxBbYvHq0m%20MaGqXSynofiDD38fmEMZAySA4EQljyNxuZIimE23X1dpUACMVD%20knoEaOjIYUk4nA2AD1qSGymGfTB0PSo9DYbb4agEwAmKjqLP0Dmto4ecIwAAWqbLFczTJzeel0sLQA)